# Xcode10 not Responding while archiving

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, freeze, xcode10

After updating to Xcode 10 when I try to archive the Unity3D app it not responding.

I tried both build systems i.e new build systems and Legacy build system and whole mac become hanged and I have to force shutdown it.

I have Macbook air 2013 core i5, 4gb ram and 250 ssd.

Comment: How big is your project and how long did you wait for it to finish? Xcode uses a lot of ram, and 4gm probably isn't enough to keep it from having to swap. For our games even 8gb isn't enough, and archiving can take an hour or more.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I'm developing games for past 3 years on this mac and never got into this kind of situation and archiving always take not more then 10 minutes. For this I have waited 45 minutes and still nothing happens. About the size of the game its simple unity mobile game with not more then 2 gb

Comment: Xcode 10.0 has a lot of issues. Are you running macOS Mojave? I'm tempted to try Xcode 10.1 Beta since the release notes have a bunch of fixes that may alleviate some of the pain of the GM 10.0.

Comment: @Alex7 I'm running macOS HighSierra. Is it worth it to update to macOS Mojaves? Is updating macOS will resolve this archiving issue?

Comment: Upgrade to Xcode 10.1 didn't help, but only downgrade to Xcode 9.

Comment: it needs lots of time to Archive it, but at last it can do it :) i face this issue too...

Comment: It looks like an issue described in this post:
[Xcode 10 not being able to archive project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52389664/xcode-10-not-being-able-to-archive-project/54628316#54628316)