# Xcode 10: No setting for Valid Architectures

Tags: ios, xcode10

I cannot find Valid Architectures settings under Project -> Build Settings -> Architectures. 
[image]
When I try to add VALID_ARCHS setting manually by clicking on + on top right, it gives an error

> There already is another setting named "VALID_ARCHS". Please enter a
>   different name.

But the setting is not visible.

There is a problem creating an archive in Xcode 10 with an error

> 'Abort Trap: 6' error in 'UICircularProgressRing'

I am trying to follow the solution provided in this answer:
[Xcode 10 not being able to archive project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52389664/xcode-10-not-being-able-to-archive-project) but cannot find Valid Architectures Setting in Xcode 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hidden under 'Basic'. Click 'All' to see it

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It might help others. I did following things - don't know what helped but I was able to archive my app

Remove armv7 from valid architectures of a private dynamic framework that I was using.
Converted my project code to Swift 4.2 (It was swift 4 before).
Deintegrate/Integrate Pods again (Manually set the swift version to 4 for those that do not support swift 4.2 yet).

I still don't have an option of setting valid architectures for my Xcode project.