# Xcode 10 - invalid bitcode signature while archiving

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10, bitcode

After switching to Xcode 10, I've been getting **invalid bitcode signature** when I try to archive. 
After hours of struggle, I stumbled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52389664/xcode-10-not-being-able-to-archive-project) and was able to archive after removing `armv7` from valid architectures.

I really cant release the app with `armv7` removed since there are lot of users who uses `iPhone 4s` & will be in dark if I do this.

I use both static and dynamic frameworks in my application and all of them support armv7 architecture by default.

Did anyone else face this issue? Is there a workaround to include `armv7` as valid architecture?

Comment: Is the target and the project's `Architecture` still set to the defaults (not **bold**)?

Comment: yep. both are set as Standard architectures - $(ARCHS_STANDARD) [not **bold**]

Comment: there are a lot of users who use iPhone 4s? Really?

Comment: The recycled iPhone community around the world use iPhone 4s. Just because it is old, this does not mean it i irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Set Build Active Architecture Only is Yes

[image]