# Xcode 10 : Not possible to archive with ARMv7

Tags: ios, xcode, armv7

I encountered an issue since I updated to Xcode 10. Archiving my project leads to an infinite stuck. As I found in [this Stackoverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52389664/xcode-10-not-being-able-to-archive-project/), we can fix this by removing ARMv7 from valid architectures. It did work for me, but it seems super weird : does it mean this is the end for ARMv7 iOS architectures ? As I could see it in [this very useful matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKZE4.png), devices like iPhone 5 or iPhone 5C use ARMv7 and, when they are up-to-date, use iOS 10.3.3 (which is kind of recent). So, this is the end ? We can not build apps for them anymore ?
If there is a way to continue to archive with both ARM64 ans ARMv7 architectures, I would be glad to know how.

Thanks for your concern.

Comment: Are you sure you are building for iOS 10.3.3, or have you downloaded the latest XCode and are building for iOS 12.1?

Comment: This is a guess, but have you tried building with the legacy build system? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51205221/

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: @newenglander Nope, never get this working. But actually, I realized it's not a big deal. People who still have iPhone 5 or iPhone 5C are happy with that, and won't be much interested by recent apps. I heard it on an Apple conference : Do not worry too much about compatibility on older devices. It's not important at all.