# Archiving project stuck for hours

Tags: swift, xcode, archive

Hello My App is already on app store uploaded with same method archive project and upload it , now i have done some little bit changes, so when ever now i archive project it got stuck on some points for hours but not complete

what i have Done

1. Deleted all derived data
2. Deleted Archive Projects
3. Tried with bitcode NO

[Xcode 10 not being able to archive project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52389664/xcode-10-not-being-able-to-archive-project/)

you can see image that archive stuck here
[image: Stuck Image]

it was working before and on some other projects also properly no issue, but on this project after updating xcode to 10.2 facing this issue

Comment: Can you check the warnings in Xcode 10.2?

Comment: Did you check with older version of Xcode as you said after updating xcode you are facing this issue.

Comment: yes these warning are related to pods

Comment: @Shahrukh but i am using Xcode 10.2 now

Comment: Yes I know just want to know this is xcode problem or your project's problem

Comment: i need to archive using this

Comment: this post solved my problem https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/115303

Answer (score 7):

A bit late to provide an answer but I ran to the same problem today.

Building and installing my app on my device works like a charm, but archiving was a different story. Every time, I was stuck to step 1225 of 1235.

Clean all cash, removing all derived data, even restarting my Mac didn't change a thing.

**I finally found the solution that worked for me.**

Using CocoaPod, I could solve this issue by moving the **Upload DSYM** build script phase to the en of the list

```swift
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols" -gsp "${PROJECT_DIR}/YourProjectName/Beta/GoogleService-Info.plist" -p ios "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"
# /!\ this script should always be the last one of the list /!\
```

Comment: can you show me please where you put that line of code?

Comment: On your Xcode project target > build phases

Comment: I was struck in a look into trying to archive my builds. This worked for me as well!

Comment: This is such an obscure answer. Not every app has this run script but mine did. I'm glad I came across this without tearing my hair out. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

Changing optimization level to "no optimization" for all pods solved it for me.

Select your Pods project and highlight all Targets, go to build settings and search for "optimization level" and set it to "No optimization"

[image: optimization level]

Source: [Xcode 11 stuck on archiving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58001433/xcode-11-stuck-on-archiving)

Answer (score 1):

Change below build settings of swift compiler - code generation and try

Compilation Mode - Incremental (Instead Whole Module) 
Optimization Level - No Optimization

Comment: I just had this same issue with Xcode 15.2 trying to archive a visionOS app. Changing Compilation Mode to Incremental made the issue go away.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue in my **multi-modular SPM project** which has a dependency on Realm. Building was fine, but when archiving everything was stuck.
The solution was to change **Package.swift** target dependency from

```
.product(name: "Realm", package: "realm-swift")
```

to

```
.product(name: "RealmSwift", package: "realm-swift")
```

Hope this will help somebody having a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptom - the archiving process got stuck as it was almost finished. My problem was that the Metro port 8081 was taken by another application. As soon as I closed the other application the archiving worked.