# Xcode 11 stuck on archiving

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode11

I‘m using Xcode 11 GM 2 to archive my app. It uses CocoaPods and Swift.
When trying to archive my app, it infinitely gets stuck here:
[image: error]
This still happens after removing Firebase or other frameworks. Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: Is it working with latest Xcode 10 or it's an Xcode 11 specific problem?

Comment: @balazs630 I can't test because the app is built with iOS 13 specific features so building in Xcode 10 fails

Comment: @SergStav I‘m on macOS Mojave and I didn‘t get that project to archive. I created a new project without CocoaPods though, copied the source code, used Carthage instead, switched to the legacy build system (File > Project Settings), then got it stuck on „Setting mode for 1 of 1 files“, deleted Derived Data, did a clean (Command + K (+Shift)) and it did archive. (I also had an issue with RMessage, which had a „Frameworks“ folder nested in it which contained another framework, that folder needed to be deleted, also check for large dictionaries in frameworks, try to remove or split them)

Comment: @thatmarcel what exactly solved your issue I'm having the same issue on Xcode 11.5 Catalina after adding the firebase Crashlytics run script in build phases it the archives never ends

Comment: i am also facing the same issue on XCode 12.1, did anyone manage to fix this issue?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This could help (I was having an issue with `SwiftSoup`, another CocoaPod). I was experiencing inexplicable hangs while trying to get Xcode 11 to archive my app (even at the command line). This is not meant to be a permanent fix, but rather a temporary workaround (in other words, we shouldn't have to do this to get a problematic library to build)!

Add this to the bottom of your `Podfile` and re-run `pod install`.

```rb
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    next unless target.name == '<NAME OF POD>'
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      next unless config.name.start_with?('Release')
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL'] = '-Onone'
    end
  end
end
```

Then try to archive your project. If that doesn't work… perhaps try messing around with other compiler optimization settings?

Comment: I was using SwiftSoup and that solution worked for me as well. Thanks!

Comment: @BenKreeger  Thanks for your work around (with the target name fixed!). It apparently works for some people, but not for me. I have also directly turned off the Swift Optimization flag in the Project settings.  I am using Xcode 11 release and SwiftSoup 2.2.1 and the Archive process still hangs while linking SwiftSoup right after the "touch".   Any thoughts??

Comment: I had SwiftSoup too. this solution worked for me too.

Comment: Swap the *config.name* from `Release` to `Alpha` if you need to upload the build to Fabric Crashlytics. That was my case a well!

Comment: Am stuck my own project. how can i find the issue?

Comment: Yes, seems like SwiftSoup was the issue. I re-generated the project with Carthage and it still woudn't compile until I removed SwiftSoup

Comment: THANK YOU... that fixed it - SwiftSoup was the culprit in my case as well

Comment: SwiftSoup had a code optimization which exposed a compiler bug. For a brief time, the fix was to use a non standard tool chain, but eventually the Swift compiler was fixed and using the current compiler tool chain in Xcode (I believe since 11.4) is the correct answer.

Answer (score 9):

I have found a clean and quick solution in the meantime, click "Pods" in the project navigator, then in targets (picture) set SwiftSoup,

[image]

In Swift compiler set both -Onone. Now try to archive.

[image]

Comment: I was using SwiftSoup and this fix my problem. Xcode was listing other pods like Alamofire or some Firebase pod, but after remove SwiftSoup optimisation, I manager to archive