# Xcode 11 - Product / Archive stuck on Notification Extension

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode11

I am using Xcode 11 (11A420a) with Swift 4 and since the upgrade, I cannot archive my app for upload to Appstore, it gets stuck on building my notification extensions.

I have tried:

- Changing Compilation Mode from Whole Module to Incremental
- Changing Optimization Level from Optimize for Speed to either
  Optimize for
- Size or No Optimization
- Tried different values for Exclusive Access to Memory
- Turned on/off disable safety check

by following this thread
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/115303 but with no luck

What is a workaround around this?

Comment: Hi, I am also stuck on the same problem. Did you find any workaround ?

Comment: No. But I saw a new post on 23 oct on the link I posted and did not try yet because I switched to xcode 10.3. If you test it, please let me know if it works

Comment: Posted text: "I still have this bug, but after removing optimisation for SwiftSoup pod (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58355036/3283808), I manager to Archive"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually worked for me:

"I still have this bug, but after removing optimisation for SwiftSoup pod (stackoverflow.com/a/58355036/3283808), I manager to Archive"