# Unable to Archive on Xcode 11 using realm

Tags: ios, react-native, realm, archive, xcode11.1

**Unable to Archive using Xcode 11.1**

Able to build an archive on Xcode 10.3 but archive not generating on Xcode 11

**Steps**:-

1.) Install latest or old 'realm'

2.) Link the realm using - react-native link realm

3.) Start generating and archive.

4.) Fails to generate archive

**Error** :-

GCDWebServers target :-

1. /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/SecProtocolTypes.h:187:18: Unknown type name 'SecTrustRef'
2. /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSURLCredential.h:9:9: Could not build module 'Security'
3. /Users/impadmin/Documents/Projects/ReactNativeProjects/MainBoilerPlate/node_modules/realm/vendor/GCDWebServer/GCDWebServer/Core/GCDWebServerHTTPStatusCodes.h:31:9: Could not build module 'Foundation'

**Version**:-

react-native: "0.61.1"

realm: "3.3.0"

xcode:11.1

ios:13

[image: Archive Failure error]

Comment: May be [helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58001433/xcode-11-stuck-on-archiving)

Comment: That module `GCDWebServers` is close to 5 years old and really needs to be updated. 

Get a an updated and current (Swift 5) version from their [site](https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer)