# Flutter iOS - Cannot archive project via xCode after add Notification Extension Service

Tags: ios, flutter, push-notification, xcode14

I added **Notification Extension Service** for push notification image purpose. It can running on read device as expected

but when I tried to archive it, some errors appears, look like the following :

[image: Undefined Symbol : OBJC_CLASS$_FlutterBasicMessageChannel]

The error message :

```
Could not find or use auto-linked framework 'Flutter'

Undefined symbol: _FlutterMethodNotImplemented

Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FlutterBasicMessageChannel

Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FlutterError

Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FlutterMethodChannel

Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FlutterStandardMessageCodec

Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FlutterStandardReader

Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FlutterStandardReaderWriter

Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FlutterStandardTypedData

Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FlutterStandardWriter

Undefined symbol: _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FlutterStandardReader

Undefined symbol: _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FlutterStandardReaderWriter

Undefined symbol: _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FlutterStandardWriter
```

I have tried some solutions that provided on internet like :

```
1. TargetSettings -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources -> add your .m class  ->Build and Run
2. Set development target of extension must equal to runner's development target
3. Clean and build folder for severals time, but still doesn't work
```

Those solutions above have no good result, still face the errors.

Just info, I got this after update to XCode 14 and add Notification Extension Services

If there's any solution that I have to try, please let me know, I appreciate it very much.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After tried everything that possible, finally I able to solved my problem. The last thing that I tried was :

Change Project Runner Configuration for Release to NONE

[image: Configuration for Runner]

But, maybe this is not the final way to solve the similar problem. If above solutions don't work, the please try this solutions as well :

1. TargetSettings -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources -> add your .m class  ->Build and Run
2. Set development target of extension must equal to runner's development target
3. Target -> Runner -> Build Phases, scroll down and find **Compile Resource** -> Add your **.m** file
4. Clean and build folder for severals time,

but don't forget to do **Pod Update** everytime you edit xcode component ( just to re-ensure everything is work )

I hope this solution can help other member who face the same issue.

Info, the issue come when i use this :

- xCode 14
- Notification service Extension

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure that the extension does have the release variation build.

I faced this problem because I was running an "archive," the "Release" build variation is used, but the extension does not have this build variation. How can you add the release build variation to the extension? I continue creating when I add a new extension without using this build variation and the problem solved.

Comment: Actually I have several variant for my application ( dev, qa and prod). Could you please add more detail about your solution ( if possible please add step by step )

Comment: I will just give me sometimes

Comment: please take a look to this issues (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58001433/xcode-11-stuck-on-archiving/58355036#58355036)

Comment: I just followed step by step and set No Optimization ( onOne ) -> pod update -> clean & build -> archive -> failed with the same errors appears. is it related with xcode version 14?

Comment: in-fact I tried this solution with Xcode version 13 and worked for me, so the problem with Xcode 14 I will look and return when finding a solution

Comment: Okay, thank you. If there is any update please mention me here. I a bit frustrated with this configuration

Comment: @Yokaha is there any news actually I looked up but with out no findings. I am sorry bro